# Statistical independence of two events

Tags: probability, statistics, independence

I hope you are doing well.

I have a  few silly doubts about the concept of statistical independence.

1. Let A and B be two events. Suppose that the probabilities of P(A) and P(B) are null and yet, that the act of measuring one event does not necessarily affect the other. Based on the above, is it possible to take  A and B as statistical independence events?

2.Would you mind suggest me references that illustrate the case above?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Probability of measure is an incorrect statement. Use (probability) measure instead.

Comment: Hi @Jack. Thank you so much for the feedback.

Comment: An event with zero probability is independent of any other event.

Comment: Hi @herbsteinberg. I hope you are doing well. Thanks. One last thing. If the expected value of event A is zero,  would it imply  P(A)=0?

Comment: @ViniciusHolmes No!!!  The expected value is simply the average.  Example: coin flips $P(1 (heads))=P(-1 (tails))=1/2$.